# gatsby-plugin-google-analytics + Shopify - Conversions not working

Tags: google-analytics, shopify, gatsby

I have a Gatsby site sourcing from Shopify, and I'm having a hard time getting the Acquisition Conversions working.

My guess is that when they go to the Checkout page, since it's on Shopify's domain, it sees that as Direct traffic.

My current configuration is:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
  options: {
    trackingId: "...",
    head: true,
    anonymize: false,
    respectDNT: false,
    allowLinker: true,
  },
},
```

I just added that `allowLinker` in to test today.  Is there anything else I'm missing?  I'm not too familiar with analytics I'm just a humble javascript farmer.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics recently changed their API to version 4 and upon other things, they changed the way the tracking identifier is set to the page. I suppose that the plugins will migrate soon to that changes but in the meantime, this is the only plugin available that works with that new API version: [`gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag/). So:

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
      options: {
        // You can add multiple tracking ids and a pageview event will be fired for all of them.
        trackingIds: [
          "GA-TRACKING_ID", // Google Analytics / GA
          "AW-CONVERSION_ID", // Google Ads / Adwords / AW
          "DC-FLOODIGHT_ID", // Marketing Platform advertising products (Display & Video 360, Search Ads 360, and Campaign Manager)
        ],
        // This object gets passed directly to the gtag config command
        // This config will be shared across all trackingIds
        gtagConfig: {
          optimize_id: "OPT_CONTAINER_ID",
          anonymize_ip: true,
          cookie_expires: 0,
        },
        // This object is used for configuration specific to this plugin
        pluginConfig: {
          // Puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
          head: false,
          // Setting this parameter is also optional
          respectDNT: true,
          // Avoids sending pageview hits from custom paths
          exclude: ["/preview/**", "/do-not-track/me/too/"],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

All the above parameters are optional, just omit them and replace the `GA-TRACKING_ID` for your real identifier.

Comment: Cool!  Thank you.  Do I need to set up GTAG for this or can I just use normal analytics?  And this will automatically work with the cross domain shopify issue of not attributing sales?

Comment: You can use both approaches, the normal `GA` and the `G` (from the new API)

Comment: Oh I see now, so I can just pass `allowLinker: true` into `gtagConfig`.  With that, now Analytics should see those Shopify conversions?

Comment: Shopify's integration could be more tricky. Try it out and come back with the results. I will look for further details if it fails.

Comment: Thanks - I owe you a drink.  So it seems I need to pass a `clientId` [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain).  I'm trying to figure out how to get the `clientId` out of the browser but having a hard time (esp since you can't test in development).  This has to be easier than I'm making it.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If the issue has been solved please accept the answer to close the issue :)

Comment: Currently nothing has changed other than using the new gtag.  Right now the continuing problem is configuring the linker to interact with Shopify's GA

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you ever solved it @cYberSport91, but in the year 2021 AD I am trying to do the same. This is what I found:

Place this snippet in your gatsby-ssr.js or gatsby-browser.js:

```js
exports.onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
  const attachCode = `
if (ga) {
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['destination1.com', 'destination2.com']);
}`

  setPostBodyComponents([<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: attachCode
  }}/>])
}
```

Source: [Gatsby Git Issues](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/13117)

(Still waiting to confirm with my client whether this solution works)

Comment: Hey! Did your client confirm that it worked?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately Dennis. I haven’t heard back, so I take that as a good sign. I’ll update here otherwise.

Comment: I got help from someone and he told me to change the checkout which is on myshopify.com to a checkout.yourdomain.com subdomain. Like this it is not cross domain anymore and conversions are working like expected.